# Class definition order

Tags: class, typescript

Can someone explain why the following typescript code compiles? It seems to me that it could never successfully run.

```
class Xyz
    {
    static x : Abc = new Abc();
    }

class Abc
    {

    }
```

Comment: Why not? I don't see any problem with it...

Answer (score 1):

There is no compile-time error, since it is equivalent to this syntactically valid JavaScript

```
var Xyz = (function () {
    function Xyz() {
    }
    Xyz.x = new Abc();
    return Xyz;
})();
var Abc = (function () {
    function Abc() {
    }
    return Abc;
})();
```

but it will have a runtime error since you try to instantiate a member of `Abc` before `Abc` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't do any enforcement of ordering of constructs in your code. Consider some slight variant that *would* be valid -- it's not immediately obvious what things should be allowed or disallowed in terms of ordering.

```
class Xyz
    {
    static x = () => new Abc();
    }

class Abc
    {

    }
```

There's an [issue tracking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21) adding this as an option for the straightforward cases.